# Pandas agg multiple summaries on same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following statement:

```
print p.df.groupby(by="Sector").agg({"Average % Weight Port":"sum","Average % Weight Port":"mean"})
```

Which gives me:

Average % Weight Port

Sector
Cash                                         0.16

Consumer Discretionary                       9.36

Consumer Staples                             6.60

Energy                                       7.41

Financials                                  14.02

Health Care                                 12.43

Industrials                                 20.45
....

aka only one column. how do i get two summary statistics on one column?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

A dictionary can only have one value associated with a key, so that syntax won't work.  There are two other options that come to mind to get a similar output: you could select the column using brackets, and then pass a list of the reduction operations you want to apply:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"sector": ["a","a","b","b"], "AWP": [10,20,30,32]})
>>> df.groupby("sector")["AWP"].agg(["sum", "mean"])
        sum  mean
sector           
a        30    15
b        62    31
```

Or you could still use a dictionary, but use a list of operations as the value:

```
>>> df.groupby("sector").agg({"AWP": ["sum", "mean"]})
       AWP     
       sum mean
sector         
a       30   15
b       62   31
```

Note that in this last version you preserve the information about the name of the aggregated column.

If you want differently-named columns, you could add a `.rename(columns={"sum": "s2"})`, or use a dictionary as the value:

```
>>> df.groupby("sector").agg({"AWP": {"newsum": "sum", "newmean": "mean"}})
          AWP        
       newsum newmean
sector               
a          30      15
b          62      31
```

Comment: Is there a way to rename the column when using `.groupby("x").agg({"ABC":"sum"})`

Comment: This last one seems simple, but I get a `SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported` ? any idea what that could be?